# Is the equation differential?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can anybody tell me if the following equation is differentiable. The equation is $\ln(\sin^2x)$ with points $[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}]$

I am learning about Mean Value Theorem, and being differentiable is one rules for MVT.

Please Help!!

Comment: Most common functions with name, such as $\ln$ and $\sin$ are diferenciable, and they keep that feature through addition, multiplication and composition **as longer** as they are defined in points and interval of choice.

Comment: Yes, in your interval $\sin^2 x$ stays away from $0$. The function $\sin^2 x$ is differentiable everywhere, and $\ln u$ is differentiable everywhere it is defined.

Comment: Just a few tangential remarks: (1) an _equation_ is a statement $A = B$: there must be an equals sign for it to be called an equation. What you are asking about is a _function_. (2) I have retagged your question. For many of the more commonly used tags on the website, if you hover your mouse over the tag you can see a short description. In the future that can help you choose more appropriate tags yourself. (3) Generally one only speak of differentiability on _open_ intervals, and not closed ones, since the usual definition requires the left and right limits agree....

Comment: ... and on closed intervals at the end points, you only have one-sided limits.